# Volume of the solid in the first octant bounded by the cylinder $z=9-y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the volume of the solid in the first octant bounded by the cylinder $z=9-y^2 $ and the plane $x=2$

Can I solve this problem using triple integrals in the following way

$$\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{9-z}}\int_0^{9-y^2}1 \, dzdydx$$

I'm currently studying double integrals in my course but I'm not entirely sure how to attack the problem that way. Doing a bit of research I found a problem about a solid prism with similar bounds. I was wondering if I could solve the problem with triple integrals and if so would it be a better option than with double?

I'm *not* looking for a solution just to let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate the volume of this solid, a triple iterated integral is fine. Note that the solid is given by
$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\;:\; 0\leq x\leq 2,\; 0\leq y,\; 0\leq z\leq 9-y^2\}.$$
So your upper integration limit for $y$ is not correct (and according to the order of integration, in any case it should not depend on $z$). 
What is the right upper limit for $y$?

Comment: Right! if I let $z=0$ I get $y=\pm 3$. Since $y \ge 0$ that gives the bounds as $$0 \le y \le 3$$

Comment: @PatrickMoloney Correct!